# How to compile POSIX timer

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, posix

I'm trying to create a timeout function (`enable_timeout`) using POSIX timers in a multithreaded program. I need to force that the calling thread of this function is the one receiving and handling the `SIGALRM` signal. For that, I have the following code, which is based on the `man timer_create` with a few modifications:

```
void procman_enable_timeout(int msec)
{
    timer_t timerid;
    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec its;

    // Disable the signal:
    procman_sig_disable(SIGALRM);

    // Will send the signal to the calling thread.
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID;
    sev.sigev_notify_thread_id = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    // Signal to be sent:
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGALRM; 
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;

    // Create the timer:
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid); // Does not start it. 


    // Configure the timer to expire after the specified interval:
    its.it_value.tv_sec = (msec/1000);
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = (msec*1000000)%1000000;
    // Will not be periodic:
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    // Install and enable signal handler:
    sigalrm_catched = false;
    procman_sig_enable(SIGALRM);

    // Start timer:
    timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL);

    while(!sigalrm_catched)
        pause(); // Waits for the reception of a SIGALRM (or any other signal!)
    sigalrm_catched = false;

    // Disable signal handler:
    procman_sig_disable(SIGALRM);
}
```

However, when I try to compile it (using `-lrt` option) GCC outputs the following:

```
procman.c:137:8: error: ‘struct sigevent’ has no member named ‘sigev_notify_thread_id’
 sev.sigev_notify_thread_id = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    ^
```

What am I missing? I included both `time.h` and `signals.h`. Shouldn't it just work?

**Edit:** I am also using `pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK)`. ***@alk*** suggested to define POSIX.1b to include POSIX timers, but that removed this functionality.

Comment: You are on Linux, are you?

Comment: You probably might need to define `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L` to have POSIX timers et al available.

Comment: Yeap, I'm on Linux, sorry I didn't mention! Defining POSIX standard to 199309L this problem was solved. However, it makes me lose PHTREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK functionality. Is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

To have POSIX timer events available the define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` need to be set to **at least** `199309L`:

```
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

For the most recent POSIX features you might try setting it to `200809L`, like

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

For details on the various possilities on this please see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

Comment: That's exacltly what I thought, but it yielded the following output:
`proccman_time.c:35:8: error: ‘struct sigevent’ has no member named ‘sigev_notify_thread_id’` and also 
`procman_time.c:35:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘syscall’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: `#define sigev_notify_thread_id _sigev_un._tid` will compile the program, although I'm not sure whether this is a good aproach or not (I found it in a Cyclictest source: http://svn.gna.org/svn/xenomai/trunk/src/testsuite/cyclic/cyclictest.c)

Comment: @CarlesAraguz: To have `syscall()` available you need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` prior to `#include`ing the appropriate headers: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html